# MSBuild with target. How can I make this work?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuild-propertygroup

I have the following code in a msbuild file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
    <ExtensionImportPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks') AND '$(DOTNETFRAMEWORK)'!='3.5'">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\</ExtensionImportPath>
    <ExtensionImportPath Condition="'$(ExtensionImportPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\</ExtensionImportPath>
</PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(ExtensionImportPath)\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

<PropertyGroup>
    <CommonTop Condition="'$(CommonTop)'==''">.</CommonTop>
    <Root>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</Root> 
    <SourceRoot>$(Root)</SourceRoot> 
    <OutputRoot>$(CommonTop)\bin</OutputRoot> 
    <OutputDebug>$(Root)\bin\Debug</OutputDebug>
</PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="compile">
    <Message Condition="'$(verbose)'=='true'" Text="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath) - empty compile target"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

That is used for all project. In each project I then have another msbuild project but I cant really get that to work ok. This is my code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Start" ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<CommonTop>.</CommonTop>
<!-- Importera top msbuild-->
<Import Project="..\\ms_top.proj"/>


<Target Name="Start">
  <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectsToBuild Include="$(CommonTop)\bulidmyHelloProject\hello.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageSubDir>myoutput\hello\Bin</PackageSubDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="StartTest" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

I call it with this parameters: /t:compile /p:verbose=true /t:target=Start

but i get error:

```
CoreCompile:
  ProjectsToBuild.Properties=
  ProjectsToBuild.AdditionalProperties=
  ProjectsToBuild=
C:\Build\hello_labb_\src\w32\msbuild.proj : error MSB4057: Target target=Start does not exist in project
```

I understand the error that it calls the first one but there is no target Start but how can I make it work? I dont want to add anything in the top msbuild file.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing  `<PropertyGroup>` around your `<CommonTop>.</CommonTop>` in the second snippet. Fix it and try - it's LGTM